# Java JSplitPane update Components directly after resizing

Tags: java, swing, size, jsplitpane

I`m trying to update my`JSplitPane` components directly after I drag the divider. I enabled instant updating of the components when I drag the divider.

My problem is that the components getting resized a bit later than I drag the divider; that looks a littlebit confusing.

[Image of my Window at resizing](http://image-upload.de/image/zgRBHK/71cb7eba56.png)

[image]

You can see the `JScrollPane` outside the window. 
I want to avoid that problem.

I tried:
- Property change listener
- Thread with 60fps

Nothing helps.

//SOLVED
Added a BorderLayout to my Panel and set the `setPreferredSize` as I need it.

Comment: `I`m trying to update my JSplitPane Components directly after i drag the divider.` - why by using - `Property Change listener - Thread with 60fps`, use LayoutManager instead

Comment: for better help sooner post an SSCCE/MCVE, short, runnable, compilable

Comment: [Don't use `setPreferredSize()` when you really mean to override `getPreferredSize()`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/230513). You can [answer your own question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/17463/163188).